# I'm getting a 0kb TXT file when scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** those informations from this code but outpout is empty:

```
<td class="views-field views-field-subscription-client-name">
                    <div>
<strong>ANNA Elliassaint René et Marjorie</strong>
<div class="show-details row-details-3390489 collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
    <p>Tél : 0671328654</p>
    <p>kartelizi9@gmail.com</p>
</div>
```

and this my code to scraping those information:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for x in range(1,4):
        numb = str(x)
        url = "https://fr.eni.com/appel-entrant-particuliers/?page="+numb
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        html =soup.contents
        html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
        records = []
        #try:
        for scrape_email in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'views-field views-field-subscription-client-name'}):
                scrape = scrape_email.text
                records.append(scrape)
        for scrape in records:
                        f = open("myfile.txt", "a+")
                        f.write(scrape)
                        f.write("\n")
                        f.close()
print("OK" +(numb))
```

and I want to **scrape** all info on all 4 pages
any solution please

Comment: What is the output if you print the html? `print(soup.prettify("utf-8"))`

Comment: output when i print the html print(soup.prettify("utf-8")), is source code  but without logins identifiant so i need to add username and password for i can get information but i don't know how i can login identifiant by xpath
//*[@id="edit-name"]
//*[@id="edit-pass"]

Comment: The reason I ask is because when I visit the link in your code, it gives me a login page.  I suspect the problem is that you need to figure out how to login before you can do the scraping you want to do.

Comment: Alexbclay thank you so much